# Theming react app with sass and css modules

Tags: reactjs, sass, css-modules

I want to implement theming in my react application. Therefore I used [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@dmitriy.borodiy/easy-color-theming-with-scss-bc38fd5734d1) (sass-mixins).

But this doesn't work in combination with css-modules, since the the theming class is outside of the css-module I want to theme.

Does anyone have a workaround for this problem or another approach to theme a react application using sass?

App.js

```
const theme = require('../../Theming.sass)

<div class={theme['theme-dark'}>
  <SearchBar/>
  ...
</div>
```

SearchBar.js

```
const styles = require('./SearchBar.scss)
const theme = require('../../Theming.sass)

<div class={styles.searchBar}>
  ...
</div>
```

SearchBar.scss

```
.searchBar {
  @include themify($themes) {
    color: themed('primary');
    background: themed('secondary');
  }

  height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
```

SearchBar.css (compiled)

```
.searchBar {
  height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.theme-light .searchBar {
  color: #fff;
  background: #bfbfbf;
}

.theme-dark .searchBar {
  color: #000;
  background: #1a1a1a;
}
```

Theming.sass

```
.theme-dark { background: #000; }

.theme-light { background: #fff; }

$themes: (
  light: (
    primary: #fff,
    secondary: #bfbfbf,
  ),
  dark: (
    primary: #000,
    secondary: #1a1a1a,
  ),
);

@function themed($key) {
  @return map-get($theme-map, $key);
}

@mixin themify($themes: $themes) {
  @each $theme, $map in $themes {

    .theme-#{$theme} & { /* HOW TO USE CSS-MODULES HERE ?*/
      $theme-map: () !global;
      @each $key, $submap in $map {
        $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), '#{$key}');
        $theme-map: map-merge($theme-map, ($key: $value)) !global;
      }

      @content;
      $theme-map: null !global;
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue, I am using SASS with CSS modules in a React app and I ended up using the theme class as a global class and not using CSS modules because every time I used the mixin it added the module prefix to the style.

I added `:global` to the theme class in the mixin:

```
@mixin themify($themes: $themes) {
  @each $theme, $map in $themes {

    :global(.theme-#{$theme}) & { 
      $theme-map: () !global;
      @each $key, $submap in $map {
        $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), '#{$key}');
        $theme-map: map-merge($theme-map, ($key: $value)) !global;
      }

      @content;
      $theme-map: null !global;
    }

  }
}
```

And I specified the class directly in my JSX in App.js:

```
<div class="theme-dark">
  <SearchBar/>
  ...
</div>
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to import `.theme-dark` through css-modules.

Should be something like:

```
<div class={styles.themeDark}>
  <SearchBar/>
  ...
</div>
```

You should also use sass-resources-loader for it: https://github.com/shakacode/sass-resources-loader

Comment: Thats a great hint. But I think I have to use the css-modules inside the mixins functions. I updated the question and marked the line inside the mixins function. Do you know how to use css-modules in this case?

Comment: This doesn't work because the mixin adds the raw class .theme-dark. We have to reference the css-module class .theme-dark inside the mixin.