# Why doesn't work scss mixins with next.js scss module import?

Tags: sass, next.js, scss-mixins

There is a  _mixins.sccs file in src/styles/ folder:

```
$themes: (
    light: (
        primary-color: #00f7ff,
        secondary-color: #373638,
    ),
    dark: (
        primary-color: #353e40,
        secondary-color: #e4e4e4,
    )
);

@mixin themed() {

    @each $theme,
    $map in $themes {
        .theme-#{$theme} & {
            $theme-map: () !global;

            @each $key,
            $submap in $map {
                $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), '#{$key}');
                $theme-map: map-merge($theme-map, ($key: $value)) !global;
            }

            @content;
            $theme-map: null !global;
        }
    }
}

@function choose($key) {
    @return map-get($theme-map, $key);
}
```

---

And the following is my next.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  sassOptions: {
    prependData: `@use 'src/styles/mixins';`,
  },
};
```

And I have a Component where I import the scss file as module:

```
//Content.tsx
import classes from "./Content.module.scss";
import Introduction from "./introduction/Introduction.view";

interface Props {}

const Content = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.content}>
      <div id="introduction"><Introduction /></div>
      <div className={classes.test}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

---

```
// Content.module.scss
.content {

    &>.test {
        height: 200px;
        @include mixins.themed() {
            background: mixins.choose('primary-color');
        } 

    }
}
```

---

If I use themed() from my mixins namespace like this, it's look like nothing happens.
Only the 200px height is displayed to my "test" class.

Dev Tools Screenshot

[image: Dev Tools Screenshot]

If I simply tried without next.config.js, it didn't work either. I am thinking here that I add @use to all of my sass module file like that:

```
// Content.module.scss
@use "src/styles/mixins";
    .content {
    
        &>.test {
            height: 200px;
            @include mixins.themed() {
                background: mixins.choose('primary-color');
            } 
    
        }
    }
```

I tried the [sass-resources-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-resources-loader) npm package, but it didn't want to work either. Unfortunately, it doesn't even support webpack5 ...

So has anyone experienced a similar difficulty before?
How to use mixins in single modul files?
By the way in global scss file which i can import in _app.tsx, it works fine.

Comment: @brc-dd
I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it still doesn't work for me.
`module.exports = { webpack: (config, options) => { config.module.rules.push({ test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i, use: [ "style-loader", "css-loader", { loader: "sass-loader", options: { additionalData: "@use src/styles/mixins", }, }, ], }); return config; }, };`
And I got an error with this solution [Error Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/3Jdbeta).

Could you possibly have an example code for this?

Comment: Sorry for my earlier responses. It appears that Next.js passes `prependData` and `additionalData` from `sassOptions` to the loader (ref - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/f9987b09e2cf925c2f59dc4a6c424cd3a6cd2e56/packages/next/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/index.ts#L94-L95). The issue is something completely different here. Feel free to revert back to what you did in the question. Modifying webpack config is not required in this case.

Comment: Is manually adding `@use` directive to all files working (like you've written in the last code snippet)?

Comment: @brc-dd No, unfortunately it doesn't work.
But interestingly, if I use a variable from the namespace it does.
But the `@mixin theme ()` "function" does not work from the namespace.

Comment: I made an example of my problem on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-xktchc?

Comment: Mixins are also working. Just not your one. I have tried with other mixins from the official website, all of them are working.

Comment: But what's wrong with my `@mixin themed()` logic?

Comment: Hey! I found the solution at the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60544907/13092238